# not able to import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID into my project

Tags: android-activity

I'm not able to import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID into my code is it a library problem  or should i need to update the library, since instanceID is available and many have implemented using the same.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well, and it ended up being that I had an older version of the android sdk tools. Getting the newest version from the developer website and installing the Google Play Services library again solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue. Got it resolved by compiling with the latest sdk tool versions.(Play services,build tools etc). Sample build.gradle is shown below for reference.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.bcd"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

enter code here

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.4.0'    - in case you need to keep below 65k

Comment: Thank you @kunmi, they don't list it at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup so that was helpful!

Comment: You're including the entire Play Services??