# firebase Instance ID vs android Instance ID

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

Play services API suggests that there is something called [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)

However, after including the following in Android Studio, I am unable to import InstanceID class

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:${googlePlayServicesVersion}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${googlePlayServicesVersion}"
```

Per this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130125/not-able-to-import-com-google-android-gms-iid-instanceid-into-my-project), InstanceID class should work if I include the identity play services library.

Following conversion of google cloud messaging to firebase cloud messaging, I believe, it must have been replaced by Firebase Instance ID as mentioned in the red message [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Now I am not sure if using Firebase ID should have indeed "replaced" Instance ID.

Or, maybe I am missing some library which includes InstanceID?

Comment: are you trying to add a FCM feature on your project? haven't you tried the firebase assistant yet? its I think in the tools menu

Comment: I just want to use the Instance ID which is not a FCM feature. Problem is I am unable to import InstanceID

Answer (score 2):

Yap,

I had the issue, and finally I realize that InstanceID class is a part of    `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid'` library , so you just have to add this line in your gradle build file:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:${googlePlayServicesVersion}"
```

Unless this works for me :) ...

Comment: But it is deprecated, use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().id`